# how to apply gsub in html text in R

Tags: regex, r

I have this vector in r called `t`:

```
"<!-- html table generated in R 3.0.0 by xtable 1.7-1 package -->\n<!-- Wed May 07 13:40:25 2014 -->\n<TABLE border=1>\n<TR> <TH>  </TH> <TH> Description </TH> <TH> Value </TH>  </TR>\n
```

I need to add a `bgcolor` to the `TH` propery as follows:

```
t <- gsub("\\<TH\\> Description \\<\\/TH\\> \\<TH\\> Value \\<\\/TH\\>","\\<TH bgcolor\\="#CAC740"\\> Description \\<\\/TH\\> \\<TH bgcolor\\="#CAC740"\\> Value \\<\\/TH\\>",t)
```

I've made sure that I covered all the double quotes. It looks like the gsub is not working. Any ideas what might be wrong here?

Comment: You are trying to use double quotes inside double quotes. R is not able to parse that in the way you want it to.

Comment: So, need to escape the double quotes if single quotes will not work, or use single quotes "outside" and double quotes "inside".

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could use `package:XML`.

```
library(XML)

html <- "<!-- html table generated in R 3.0.0 by xtable 1.7-1 package -->\n<!-- Wed May 07 13:40:25 2014 -->\n<TABLE border=1>\n<TR> <TH>  </TH> <TH> Description </TH> <TH> Value </TH>  </TR>\n"

doc <- htmlParse(html)

for (x in c("Description", "Value")) {
    xpath <- sprintf("//th[contains(string(.), '%s')]", x)
    node <- getNodeSet(doc, xpath)[[1]]
    addAttributes(node, bgcolor = "#CAC740")
}

f <- file()
saveXML(doc, f)

paste(tail(readLines(f), -1), collapse = "")
## [1] "<!-- html table generated in R 3.0.0 by xtable 1.7-1 package --><!-- Wed May 07 13:40:25 2014 --><html><body><table border=\"1\"><tr><th>  </th> <th bgcolor=\"#CAC740\"> Description </th> <th bgcolor=\"#CAC740\"> Value </th>  </tr></table></body></html>"
```